# std::for_each on a member function with 1 argument

Tags: c++, foreach, std

I'm wondering how to implement what is stated in the title. I've tried something like...

`std::for_each( a.begin(), a.end(), std::mem_fun_ref( &myClass::someFunc ) )`

but I get an error saying that the "term" (I"m assuming it means the 3rd argument) doesn't evaluate to a function with 1 argument, even though `someFunc` does take one argument - the type of the objects stored in `a`.

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible using the standard library (I know I can do it easily using boost).

P.S. Does using `for_each` and `mem_fun_ref` have any performance implications in comparison to just iterating through `a` manually and passing the object to `someFunc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though someFunc is a member with one parameter, mem_fun_ref uses an implicit first argument of "myClass".  You want to use the vector's items as the 2nd argument .

And there are probably no negative performance implications of using for_each and mem_fun_ref.  The compiler will generate comparable code.  But, the only way to be sure is to benchmark :)

```
  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(),
                std::bind1st(
                    std::mem_fun_ref( &MyClass::SomeFunc ),
                    my_class ));
```

Comment: I assume I would use bind2nd then. Now I'm thinking how to go about specifying to use the current element in the iteration for it. I think I'll just use boost..

Comment: Nope, still uses bind1st.  mem_fun_ref becomes a function with two arguments.  The first one is MyClass, the second one is your member function param.  You want to bind the 1st argument to mem_fun_ref to your class instance.

Comment: @Person: If you're gonna use Boost, I'd recommend using their foreach macro. `std::for_each` was simply a failed idea, and often leads for more spread-out, harder to read code.

Comment: `s/my_class/this/`. Hey, in C++03 at least, `for_each` saves the excessive tedium of declaring the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use bind_1st to supply the hidden "this" argument.  Or do you mean that the "this" argument is the only one, someFunc has no parameters of its own?

Comment: someFunc has one parameter. Like myClass::someFunc( someType ).